# Do Abelian varieties isomorphic to all their conjugates descend?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties

Suppose $A$ is an abelian variety over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ of dimension $g$, such that $A$ is isomorphic to all of its Galois conjugates. Note that I'm not including any polarization data.

Can I conclude that $A$ descends to $\mathbb{Q}$, or at least to a field $K$ of bounded degree over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Thanks!

Comment: Your assumption is that the *field of moduli* is $\mathbb Q$, but it is insufficient to ensure that the *field of definition* is $\mathbb Q$. There is an obstruction in a $H^2$.

Comment: Yeah, right! My question is how serious the obstruction is basically.

Answer (score 3):

1.Theorem (Shimura 1971, "On the Field of Rationality for an Abelian Variety"):  If $g$ = dim $A$ is odd and $Aut(A)=\{\pm1\}$ then $A$ has a model over its field of moduli.  Proof:  $\{1\} = H^1(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}^*) \rightarrow  H^2(\pm1) \rightarrow H^2(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}^*)$ and $\{\pm1\}$ acts faithfully on $H^0(A_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}, \Omega^g) = \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ since $g$ is odd, so the image of the obstruction in $H^2(Aut(H^0(A_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}, \Omega^g))) = H^2(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}^*)$ can be identified as the obstruction to the descent of a one-dimenstional $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ vector space to $\mathbb{Q}$, which is therefore trivial.

2.Of interest:

Maus 1973, "On the Field of Moduli of an Abelian Variety with Complex Multiplication"

Shimura 1982, "Models of an Abelian Variety with Complex Multiplication Multiplication over Small Fields"

Shioda 1977, "Some Remarks on Abelian Varieties"

Comment: I checked the paper, and it looks like Shimura's theorem deals with polarized abelian varieties.

Comment: Doesn't the argument apply to unpolarized varieties?  Shimura refers to generic polarized varieties, and a polarization is required to define a moduli variety.  Note Shioda's "Question 2" with the example of elliptic curves $E_1,E_2$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ such that $E_1 \times E_1 \ncong E_1 \times E_2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ but the reductions are isomorphic over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ for all $p \equiv 3$ mod(4).

Comment: Ah, of course, you're right. Can you explain your exact sequence at the beginning and where the obstruction lives exactly? I ultimately care about A=E^r, so it has a gigantic automorphism group unfortunately.

Comment: It's from the long exact Galois cohomology sequence of $1 \rightarrow \{\pm1\} \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{Q}}^* \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{Q}}^* \rightarrow 1$.  The descent obstruction is in $H^2(Aut(A))$.